# Using JavaScript to change display setting of an element if a certain DIV is loaded on page

Tags: javascript, angular

I am very new to this and I'm having challenges with the way I type out my code.

Currently on my page there is the following button:

```
<a ng-if="vm.cart.canRequestQuote" href="/Rfq" class="btn primary btn-request-quote tst_cartPage_submitQuote" ng-bind="vm.cart.isSalesperson ? 'Create a Quote' : 'Request a Quote'" ng-disabled="vm.cart.isAwaitingApproval">Request a Quote</a>
```

I am trying to hide/show this button (using JavaScript) based on whether or not the following is loaded on the page:

```
<div ng-if="product.quoteRequired" class="quote-required">
```

Please help. I've tried a number of different scripts but I think because the button is a child of the `div.tst_cartPage_buttons` that I'm not typing the element out properly in JavaScript

Thank you for any guidance you can give.

Comment: Its very hard to understand

Comment: can you add an id to each tag?

Comment: I'm not able to add an ID. (If this is a necessity I will need to hire a developer to update our base code). - Thank you.

Comment: I think you're doing angular wrong. Imma tag it for you in case someone who is good at that can help out. Maybe provide more of your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

you can use a jquery framework (https://jquery.com/) and type:

```
if ($('#idOfElementToSearch')!=null) $('#elementToHide').hide()
```

the $ function is useful for easily finding the elements because it uses the css selectors

```
$('.btn .primary .btn-request-quote .tst_cartPage_submitQuote').hide()
```

hide all element that have this 4 class

or if you don't want use a framework you can use Document.getElementById() or getelementbyclass instead of $ function, but is more harder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try hidding the button with the same condition being used on your second element.

Something like:

```
<a ng-if="product.quoteRequired" href="/Rfq" class="btn primary btn-request-quote tst_cartPage_submitQuote" ng-bind="vm.cart.isSalesperson ? 'Create a Quote' : 'Request a Quote'" ng-disabled="vm.cart.isAwaitingApproval">Request a Quote</a>
```

Also, you are using AngularJS instead of Angular 2+. I would recommend moving into Angular 2+ (currently at 8 version) to get the best of type support with Typescript.